# How is /dev populated for Android

Tags: android

I have a driver compiled and running on hardware running Android 4.3. By running, I mean 'insmod gipc' loaded the driver and it ran through initialization. It assigned the major number 243 to the driver as evident in the /proc/devices files. The example code application is looking for the following two files

```
/sys/class/gipc/gipc1/name  
/dev/gipc1
```

How should these files be created? Android does not have mknod and does not support udev. I do not really need the file in /sys/class, but without the file in /dev, I cannot access the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following functions, class_create(), device_create(), and device_create_file() to accomplish this.  Not sure if there is a more preferred way, or a way of having the files automatically created.